# How to transfer variable values between forms (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

In one of my forms I declared a global variable using "Public", and then based on the button click of a user assigned a value to the variable.

When I try to move the variable to a second form, it doesn't bring the value of the variable across with it.

Is it only bringing across the local declaration and not the assigned value?  How can I make it transfer the value also.

Thanks!

Comment: Each instance of that Form will have its own copy of that variable...so if it isn't being "brought over" then you're accessing the wrong instance of the form (you're most likely creating a new instance in an attempt to solve your problem).  You need to pass a reference to the correct instance of your form into the form that you want to access it from.  A `Public Shared` variable is **shared** by all instances of that Form.  This means that if you had multiple instances of that form, and changed the value, then all instances would be changed as well.  If that's a good thing is up to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable "Public Shared".